# Liferay custom portlet localization

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a task to localize my custom portlet. I'm trying to trick it with hook. I read that I should create hook.xml configuration and property file in my portlet project

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.2.0//EN"
 "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_2_0.dtd">

<hook>
<language-properties>resources/language.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
```

Ok. But how can I use it for my custom portlet with custom field? For example I have jsp:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${status.equals('captchaError')}">
    Captcha error //How can I localize it?
    <br />
</c:when>
<c:when test="${status.equals('numberError')}">
    Number error //How can I localize it?
    <br />
</c:when>
<c:when test="${status.equals('success')}">
    Message send //How can I localize it?
    <br />
</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

I hope my question is clear and you will help me!

Answer (score 0):

Define you messages as key-value pair in language.properties file.

e.g number-error= Number Error

And use liferay-ui:message tag to get message values. You have to declare taglib for liferay-ui tags.

e.g `<liferay-ui:message key='number-error'/>`

This tag will display value for number-error key from language properties file.

Hope this helps.